# How to parse from other websites to display in android?

Tags: android, json, api, parsing, gson

I decided to parse using json to display news in android. Some websites like weather news are providing json/xml api. Where some websites don't provide api. without api, is it possible to parse? say for eg: http://www.bbc.com/news/ i need an api to create each category by using in json. How to create json dynamically for website that doesn't provide api? Any library is there to parse and display json format for websites?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made example how to parse HTML and make JSON from them. But It is not simple. You could make parser in PHP which will output JSON and upload on your server. See my my example here http://goo.gl/IbNg0Q

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do a trick, you could write a so called «scraper» that gets the html page, extracts the content from the page and outputs it as JSON. But I guess you should do more work with PHP, you could look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php for getting started.

Answer (score 0):

`GSON`, is Google's API to parse JSON.
`Jackson API`, to parse JSON.

There are many libraries out there. You could have Googled :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. But my question is,I am asking for parsing website to Json format.

Comment: convert HTML to JSON ?

Answer (score -1):

No it is not possible to get json from websites without the api